# Retrieving multi-category data from REST Data API using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, scrapy

With help from the developers of this community, I was able to scrape data from an online [supermarket](https://eshop.nomin.mn/n-foods.html). This page shows the food category of the website. However, I have been unable to get sub-category, and sub-sub-category information for each product. For example, this [chips product](https://eshop.nomin.mn/02711246.html) I get the category **Хүнс** or "**Food**", and the **Product Name**.

However, I would like the Sub-category and Sub-sub category information shown in red in the picture below:

- **Хүнс** > **Амттан** > **Чипс** > **Чипс Orion koony**
- **Category** > **Sub-category** > **Sub-sub category** > **Product Name**

[image]

I have tested using xpath but receive an error as the data I collected using the REST API is a dict. Following some other posts on Stack Overflow, I tried using xpath on the json response like so with the Category2 xpath but to no avail:

```html
    def parse(self, response, category=None):
    data = response.json()
    if data and data['data'] and data['data']['products'] and data['data']['products']['items']:
        for item in data['data']["products"]["items"]:
            yield {
                "Барааны нэр": item["name"],
                "Category": category,
                "Category2": response.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'breadcrumbs-root-118')]/span[2]/text())").extract_first().strip(),
                "Үндсэн үнэ": item["price"]["regularPrice"]["amount"]["value"],
                "Хөнгөлөлтийн үнэ": item["special_price"],
                "Барааны тайлбар": item["short_description"]["html"],
                "Барааны код": item["sku"]
            }
```

This is the results I get with no Category2 values being scraped. I have been unsuccessful in identifying any possible sub-category, sub-sub category item values in the dict value I scrapped from the REST API except only the **category** and **product item values** or "Барааны нэр".

All help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance. The full code is provided below. Additionally, if anyone knows how to remove the HTML

tags that keep being included in the **product description** or "Барааны тайлбар". Sorry for the long post and thank you.

[image]

**Full code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from datetime import datetime
import json

categories = {
    "6011": {"pages": 60, "name": "Цахилгаан бараа"},
    "24175": {"pages": 70, "name": "Хүнс"},
    "24273": {"pages": 40, "name": "Гэр ахуй"},
    "21297": {"pages": 70, "name": "Гоо сайхан"},
    "19653": {"pages": 30, "name": "Гутал, хувцас"},
    "19451": {"pages": 10, "name": "Авто бараа"},
    "19518": {"pages": 40, "name": "Барилгын материал"},
    "19853": {"pages": 10, "name": "Аялал, Спорт бараа"},
    "19487": {"pages": 50, "name": "Ном"},
    "19767": {"pages": 20, "name": "Бичиг хэрэг"},
    "19469": {"pages": 10, "name": "Эрүүл мэнд"},
    "19545": {"pages": 20, "name": "Хүүхдийн бараа"},
}

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = dt_today + ' Nomin'


class Nomin(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nomin_cpi'
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            f'{filename}.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'overwrite': True}}
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for cat, val in categories.items():
            for page in range(1, val["pages"]):
                url = f'https://eshop.nomin.mn/graphql?query=query+category%28%24pageSize%3AInt%21%24currentPage%3AInt%21%24filters%3AProductAttributeFilterInput%21%24sort%3AProductAttributeSortInput%29%7Bproducts%28pageSize%3A%24pageSize+currentPage%3A%24currentPage+filter%3A%24filters+sort%3A%24sort%29%7Bitems%7Bid+name+sku+brand+salable_qty+brand_name+c21_available+c21_business_type+c21_reference+c21_street+c21_area+c21_bed_room+mp_daily_deal%7Bcreated_at+date_from+date_to+deal_id+deal_price+remaining_time+deal_qty+discount_label+is_featured+product_id+product_name+product_sku+sale_qty+status+store_ids+updated_at+__typename%7Dnew_to_date+short_description%7Bhtml+__typename%7DproductAttributes%7Bname+value+__typename%7Dprice%7BregularPrice%7Bamount%7Bcurrency+value+__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dspecial_price+special_to_date+thumbnail%7Bfile_small+url+__typename%7Durl_key+url_suffix+mp_label_data%7Benabled+name+priority+label_template+label_image+to_date+__typename%7D...on+ConfigurableProduct%7Bvariants%7Bproduct%7Bsku+special_price+price%7BregularPrice%7Bamount%7Bcurrency+value+__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dpage_info%7Btotal_pages+__typename%7Dtotal_count+__typename%7D%7D&operationName=category&variables=%7B%22currentPage%22%3A{page}%2C%22id%22%3A{cat}%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22category_id%22%3A%7B%22in%22%3A%22{cat}%22%7D%7D%2C%22pageSize%22%3A50%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22news_from_date%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%7D'
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    cb_kwargs={"category": val["name"]}
                )

    def parse(self, response, category=None):
        data = response.json()
        if data and data['data'] and data['data']['products'] and data['data']['products']['items']:
            for item in data['data']["products"]["items"]:
                yield {
                    "Барааны нэр": item["name"],
                    "Category": category,
                    "Category2": response.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'breadcrumbs-root-118')]/span[2]/text())").extract_first().strip(),
                    "Үндсэн үнэ": item["price"]["regularPrice"]["amount"]["value"],
                    "Хөнгөлөлтийн үнэ": item["special_price"],
                    "Барааны тайлбар": item["short_description"]["html"],
                    "Барааны код": item["sku"]
                }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(Nomin)
    process.start()
```

Comment: I'm not getting a JSON, the URL in the loop redirects me to the main page. You need to fix that. When I inspected the webpage I saw all the sub-categories in each and every category, and all sub-sub-categories. First thing first, fix the request.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late response I had no access to internet until now. I assumed I was using the data request API to scrape my data. Is that incorrect? Ideally I do not want to use a list of URL's for each category. When I use the Google Developer inspect element /network/ I cannot seem to figure out what to do. Could you please provide some suggestions? Please and thank you. @SuperUser