# How to scrape multi-categorical and multi-page data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I want to scrape data from this online [store](https://e-shop.nomin.mn/t/6011). Previously, I was able to scrape all the data I wanted **except** the category, sub-category, and sub-sub category, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76354508/retrieving-multi-category-data-from-rest-data-api-using-scrapy).

However, the website seems to have made changes recently as I got a DNSError with my allowed domain URL and also get the following error when I run the previous version of the code:

```
if data and data['data'] and data['data']['products'] and data['data']['products']['items']:
KeyError: 'data'
```

Going based on what a user commented, there seems to be a problem with my start request URL. However, I am unable to figure out what, even while using Google Developer Tools - Network. As such, I created a new scrapper to include error parsing (*the full script can be found at the very bottom of this post*), which catches the 3 errors/bugs below:

Error/Bug 1:

```
DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
```

Error/Bug 2:

```
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1582, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Error/Bug 3:

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in .//a[contains(@class, 'MuiBox-root css-1efcy4n')]/text())
```

Additionally, as I am no longer using the data API, I am having difficulty with my start requests URL and pagination. I want to scrape different categories of products that I included in a list. For example **6011 is Electrical Products**, while **24175 is Grocery**. Since the website seems to be made in JavaScript, I am also having difficulty scrapping the next page of data. Do I require selenium? splash? Please advise.

```
categories = {
    "6011": {"pages": 60, "name": "Цахилгаан бараа"},
    "24175": {"pages": 70, "name": "Хүнс"},
    "24273": {"pages": 40, "name": "Гэр ахуй"},
    "21297": {"pages": 70, "name": "Гоо сайхан"},
    "19653": {"pages": 30, "name": "Гутал, хувцас"}
}
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://e-shop.nomin.mn/t/6011", errback=self.parse_error)
```

```
        # handling pagination
        next_page = response.xpath(
            "//a[contains(@class,'number-list-next js-page-filter number-list-line')]/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
            print(f'Scraped {next_page}')
```

Full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy import Request
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = dt_today + ' E-CPI Nomin'

categories = {
    "6011": {"pages": 60, "name": "Цахилгаан бараа"},
    "24175": {"pages": 70, "name": "Хүнс"},
    "24273": {"pages": 40, "name": "Гэр ахуй"},
    "21297": {"pages": 70, "name": "Гоо сайхан"},
    "19653": {"pages": 30, "name": "Гутал, хувцас"},
    "19451": {"pages": 10, "name": "Авто бараа"},
    "19518": {"pages": 40, "name": "Барилгын материал"},
    "19853": {"pages": 10, "name": "Аялал, Спорт бараа"},
    "19487": {"pages": 50, "name": "Ном"},
    "19767": {"pages": 20, "name": "Бичиг хэрэг"},
    "19469": {"pages": 10, "name": "Эрүүл мэнд"},
    "19545": {"pages": 20, "name": "Хүүхдийн бараа"},
}

# create Spider class
class ecpiNominSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cpi_nomin"
    allowed_domains = "www.e-shop.nomin.mn"
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "FEEDS": {
            f'{filename}.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'overwrite': True}}
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://e-shop.nomin.mn/t/6011", errback=self.parse_error)

    def parse_error(self, failure):
        if failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            yield {
                'URL': request.url,
                'Status': failure.value
            }

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        cards = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'MuiBox-root css-1kmsi46')]")

        # parse details
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'MuiBox-root css-1efcy4n')]/text())").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'MuiBox-root css-qr51gz')]").extract_first().strip()
            link = card.xpath(".//a[contains(@href)]/@href").get()

            item = {'name': name,
                    'price': price,
                    'link': 'https://e-shop.nomin.mn/p/' + link
                    }
            # follow absolute link to scrape deeper level
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'item': item})

        # handling pagination
        next_page = response.xpath(
            "//a[contains(@class,'number-list-next js-page-filter number-list-line')]/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
            print(f'Scraped {next_page}')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # retrieve previously scraped item between callbacks
        item = response.meta['item']

        # parse additional details
        list_li = response.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'MuiBreadcrumbs-ol css-nhb8h9')]/text()").extract()

        # get next layer data
        cat1 = list_li[0].strip()
        cat2 = list_li[1].strip()
        cat3 = list_li[2].strip()
        cat4 = list_li[3].strip()
        skp = response.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, ' MuiBox-root css-jyp6ua')/text()").extract()

        # update item with next layer data
        item.update({
            'category': cat1,
            'sub_category': cat2,
            'sub_sub_category': cat3,
            'productName': cat4,
            'productCode': skp
        })

        yield item

        # main driver
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            process = CrawlerProcess()
            process.crawl(ecpiNominSpider)
            process.start()
```

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to figure out if I should be trying to somehow fix my previous version of the code from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76354508/retrieving-multi-category-data-from-rest-data-api-using-scrapy) or to fix my current version posted above. I would really appreciate it if you guys can assist me in scraping the website for all pages of data (including **cat1: category** and **cat2: sub-category** information). Sorry for the long post I am frustrated with myself as I have made multiple questions, queried Stackoverflow for the past few months, and can't seem to progress. Thank you once again for all the help!

Comment: well two of your xpaths have incorrect syntax... the one that you use for the `name` variable has an extra close `)` at the end...  then the one that you are using for `link` is wrong too.  change it to `//a[@href]/@href`  the contains part is not needed.  As for the rest of your question I have already answered this question before for you haven't I?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry for the late reply. I understand and thank you for your help on my previous question. However, when I use Google Developer Tools to find the data api url, it no longer exists and there does not seem to be one. Which was why I made another question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using selenium as its webdriver implementation has exactly the functionality you are looking for. For example, you could use `element.click()` and define methods that always navigate to a specific sub-category. Though it will take a little effort to get used to it.

This site has a good 'getting started' section and helps getting familiar with all important aspects when using selenium.

Introduction: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/

Selenium Docs:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/

For a python specific documentation see:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/